# A simple probability inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I am looking for a simple proof of the following inequality.

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. For any $x>0$ and $y>0$,
>   $$
> \Pr\{|X+Y|\ge x\}
> \ge\Pr\{|X|\ge x+y,|Y|\le y\}.
> $$

One way to prove this inequality is to consider all possible cases. If $\omega\in\{|X|\ge x+y,|Y|\le y\}$, $X(\omega)\ge0$ and $Y(\omega)\ge0$, then $\omega\in\{|X+Y|\ge x\}$. If $\omega\in\{|X|\ge x+y,|Y|\le y\}$, $X(\omega)\ge0$ and $Y(\omega)<0$, then $\omega\in\{|X+Y|\ge x\}$ etc. But this way seems cumbersome. Is there a simpler way to make sure that this inequality is true?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove it is by showing an inclusion between the events, i.e. that $$
\{\lvert X\rvert \geq x+y \}\cap \{\lvert Y\rvert \leq y \} \subseteq \{ \lvert X+Y\rvert \geq x \}
$$
or, in different terms, that if $\lvert X\rvert \geq x+y$ and $\lvert Y\rvert \leq y$ (the first event holds), then it is the case that $\lvert X+Y\rvert \geq x$ (the second does as well). But this is in turn an application of the (reverse) triangle inequality, as
$$
\lvert X+Y\rvert \geq \lvert X\rvert - \lvert Y\rvert \geq (x+y) - y = x.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Claim: If $|X|\ge x+y$ and $|Y|\le y$, then $|X+Y|\ge x$.

Reason: By the triangle inequality,
$
|X+Y|\ge|X|-|Y|\ge x+y -y =x
$.